# Arduino cannot write to lcd screen in loop() function

Tags: bluetooth, arduino, serial-port, arduino-uno, lcd

I am trying to print stuff on the lcd screen when receiving Serial data. it works like this:

```
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  lcd.begin(16, 2);
  lcd.write("hello");
}

void loop() {
    if (Serial.available() == 5) {
        inputByte_0 = Serial.read();
        delay(10);    
        inputByte_1 = Serial.read();
        delay(10);      
        inputByte_2 = Serial.read();
        delay(10);      
        inputByte_3 = Serial.read();
        delay(10);
        inputByte_4 = Serial.read(); 
    }
    if (inputByte_0 == 9) {
        Serial.println("hi");
        lcd.write("whats up?");
    }
}
```

It writes "hello" when it starts. it fires the message "hi" to me when i send the correct byte, but it doesn't write anything on the screen. what am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use lcd.write() function for printing strings on the LCD. Instead use the function **lcd.print("Your String")**.

lcd.write and lcd.print belong so the same class **LiquidCrystal** but the only difference is that print function will convert the argument as string but the write() function will not.

Consider using lcd.print();

Answer (score 1):

I would try using lcd.print("String") instead of lcd.write and see if that works